# Hiding all but first element of a DataList via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a `DataList` which displays three products per row. What I want is to display the 'Category' name at the top of each row. Each item contains the Category so I want to display it only on the first one and maybe on a different `div` if possible. 
At the moment I am not able to get the `Label5` so I can do some actions on it. Any ideas?

```
<div id="dvProducts">
    <asp:DataList ID="rptCustomers" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" CellPadding="0"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" visible="true" Text='<%# Eval("SubCategoryID")%>'/></label>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                 var theLabel = document.getElementById('Label5').eq(0);
                 //If theLabel is alread visible/rendered then other occurences.
                 //hide here
           </script>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</div>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div id="dvProducts">
    <table id="dnn_ctr434_View_rptCustomers" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-color:Black;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>
            <span id="dnn_ctr434_View_rptCustomers_Label5_0">1</span>


            <div class="wrapping">
                <div id="boxer">
                    <span class="Thumbnail">
                        <div class="photo_box  img_zoom">
                            <a href="http://localhost/top3/TheDetails/ProductID/17">
                                <div class="pic_box">
                                    <img src="/top3/Portals/0/thumbdesktop-wallpaper-high-resolution.png" alt="Mountain View" class="topimage">
                                    <div class="ico"><span class="glyphicons glyph-search"></span></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="ProductID">
                        <span id="dnn_ctr434_View_rptCustomers_ProductID_0">17</span></span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="Name">
                        <span id="dnn_ctr434_View_rptCustomers_Name_0">the big product</span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
        </td><td>
            <span id="dnn_ctr434_View_rptCustomers_Label5_1">1</span>


            <div class="wrapping">
                <div id="boxer">
                    <span class="Thumbnail">
                        <div class="photo_box  img_zoom">
                            <a href="http://localhost/top3/TheDetails/ProductID/14">
                                <div class="pic_box">
                                    <img src="/top3/Portals/0/images/images1/thumb10404234_10154364241210080_1593901414874601578_n.png" alt="Mountain View" class="topimage">
                                    <div class="ico"><span class="glyphicons glyph-search"></span></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="ProductID">
                        <span id="dnn_ctr434_View_rptCustomers_ProductID_1">14</span></span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="Name">
                        <span id="dnn_ctr434_View_rptCustomers_Name_1">Test</span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
        </td><td>
            <span id="dnn_ctr434_View_rptCustomers_Label5_2">1</span>


            <div class="wrapping">
                <div id="boxer">
                    <span class="Thumbnail">
                        <div class="photo_box  img_zoom">
                            <a href="http://localhost/top3/TheDetails/ProductID/24">
                                <div class="pic_box">
                                    <img src="/top3/Portals/0/Templates/thumb10502496_10154364240805080_26951325019847038_n.png" alt="Mountain View" class="topimage">
                                    <div class="ico"><span class="glyphicons glyph-search"></span></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="ProductID">
                        <span id="dnn_ctr434_View_rptCustomers_ProductID_2">24</span></span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="Name">
                        <span id="dnn_ctr434_View_rptCustomers_Name_2">fasdf</span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add in the HTML code that gets generated?  Also, `id` **must be unique**.  If you need more than one of the same value, use a `class` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `id` attribute **must be unique**.  If you need more than one, then you should use `class` instead. In this particular case, you don't need either.

Add this in a `script` tag:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('[id*=Label5]').hide().each(function(i){
    if ( !(i % 4)) { $(this).show(); }
  });
});
```

You can see it [on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83q6xcud/2/).

Comment: Gary, I have edited the question and added the rendered html. I am using ascx controls so I can't add your code before the </body>, I have added it below the DataList in <script type="text/javascript"></script> block but so far it does not work...

Comment: Please not that I'm using  the label like this: <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" visible="true" Text='<%# Eval("SubCategoryID")%>'/></label>

Comment: @alwaysVBNET  The script will not work there.  The page needs to be rendered before it will work. And it needs to be on there only once.  And again the `id` attribute must be unique;  This is invalid `<div id="boxer">` because it appears more than once.

Comment: Maybe add as the last line outside of the `itemteplate` area before the `div`?

Comment: I have tested some other javascript in terms of the location and it worked. I have also added it outside the itemtemplate before the </div> but still no luck

Comment: what does "no luck" mean? Did you get an error? If so what was the error?

Comment: There is no actual label being added so the code will not work as is.  Which area is the actual "label"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80318/discussion-between-alwaysvbnet-and-gary-storey).

Comment: with no luck I meant it doesn't work. The label renders as "dnn_ctr434_View_rptCustomers_Label5_0".

Comment: Updated to use the `span`

Comment: I have tried the span, but it still doesn't work. Would you like to have a look via teamviewer?

Comment: Updated one last time.